# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: http.Agent is not a constructor

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to use Stripe. When I tried the code below, 'http.Agent is not a constructor' error thrown.

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = new Stripe('<my test key>', {
        apiVersion: '2022-11-15',
    });
```

Error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: http.Agent is not a constructor
    at node_modules/stripe/lib/net/NodeHttpClient.js (NodeHttpClient.js:6:26)
    at __require2 (chunk-NNYXQWFV.js?v=619287ea:19:50)
    at Stripe.createNodeHttpClient (stripe.js:117:28)
    at new Stripe (stripe.js:89:44)
    at myStripe (stripe.ts:8:20)
    at [lessonid].vue:189:5
    at runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2723:40
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:155:22)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:164:21)
    at hook.__weh.hook.__weh (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2697:29)
```

**Environment:**

```
Node ^17.0.0
stripe ^11.3.0
MacOS
Typescript
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details about your integration, like sharing all the package.json ?
You can run this stripe nodejs-typescript sample project and check the full configuration:
https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-payment/tree/main/custom-payment-flow/server/node-typescript

Comment: Sounds like you're using stripe-node(a backend library) in frontend code(Vue?) which is why you get an error, you're not actually running it in a Node server.